# axios/laravel/formdata post request is empty

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, axios, form-data

I want to upload some files, but when i post with axios, my formdata is an empty request in laravel

vuejs: uploader.vue

```
filesChange(e) {
    const fileList = e.target.files;
    const formData = new FormData();
    if (!fileList.length) return;
    for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i += 1) {
      console.log(fileList[i]);
      formData.append('files', fileList[i], fileList[i].name);
    }
    this.save(formData);
  },
```

output from console, all files are looped and appended to formData
[image: output from console, all files are looped and appended to formData]

```
save(formData) {
    photosApi.storePhotos(formData, this.galleryId).then((response) =>     {
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
},
```

vuejs: photosApi.js

```
storePhotos(formData, id) {
    return axios.post(`api/photo/${id}`, formData);
},
```

when i inspect my api-call i see this
[image: when i inspect my api-call i see this]

laravel: api.php

```
Route::post('/photo/{id}',  'PhotoController@store');
```

laravel: PhotoController.php

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    return $request->all(); 
}
```

the return of my response is only empty...
[image: the return of my response is only empty...]

what im'doing wrong?

Comment: try to return json response.

Comment: @pdshah3690 also empty with return response()->json($request->all());

Comment: @ParthShah with print_r($request->all()); you can inspect the data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it finally :)

the first problem was this line

```
formData.append('files', fileList[i], fileList[i].name);
```

append was always overwriting the last "files" entry... (i thought it was working like push)

so the first fix was

```
formData.append(`file${i}`, fileList[i], fileList[i].name);
```

to see the data don't use

```
return $request->all();
```

instead use

```
print_r($request->all());
```

now you can see something usefull when you inspect your apicall

[image]

now it was easy

```
$data = $request->all();
foreach ($data as $key => $file) {
    $file->move('/public/images', $file->getClientOriginalName());
};
```

all my files are stored in my folder ;)

**UPDATE:**
**I found out, if i write files with "[]" then i get also the data as an array**

```
for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i += 1) {
    formData.append('files[]', fileList[i], fileList[i].name);
}
```

And in my controller i get access to my files with this line, but without the "[]"

```
$files = $request->file('files');
```